# Is it possible to create a translator in LiveCode for my app which translates any text in the app?

Tags: jquery, livecode

Is it possible to create a translator in LiveCode for my app which translates any text in the app?
I've tried embeding the google translate however it wasn't successful

Thankyou

Comment: Wondering if you checked - https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs

Comment: Can you provide details how did you try google translate APIs?

Comment: https://translate.google.com/manager/website/

Comment: I tried to use the code for embeding it for a website

Answer (score 0):

To incorporate Google Translate into your LiveCode app, you will have to use the Google Translate API. It is documented at https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/using_rest.  Keep in mind that unlike other Google web services, Translate is a paid service, so you would have to subscribe to use it over the long term. There does appear to be a free trial, however, so you can try it out before you decide. See the "Free Trial" link on the documentation page.

Using RESTful APIs like this one is straightforward in LiveCode. The easiest way to try it out is to find an example URL query to the service. One is included in the documentation page linked to above:
https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY&q=hello+world&source=en&target=de

The URL query string is composed of a base URL followed by a series of name=value pairs. In this example, notice that the first name=value pair is an API key. You have to obtain this key by signing up for the service. The next name=value pair is the text to be translate, "hello world", encoded for transmission through the internet. That is followed by the source language, English, and the target language, German. 
In LiveCode you would something like the following in your script:

```
put "en" into tSourceLangCode
put "de" into tTargetLangCode
put "?key=YOUR-API-KEY-HERE" into tArgList
put "&q=" & urlEncode("hello world") after tArgList
put "&source=" & tSourceLangCode & "&target=" & tTargetLangCode after tArgList
put "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2" & tArgList into tURLstr
put URL URLstr into tResult
```

This service appears to return its results as JSON encoded text, so you would have to either convert the JSON to a LiveCode array, or parse out the translation yourself. In LiveCode 8 and above there is a built in JSON library that will convert JSON to an array with a simple function call.

```
put jsonImport(tResult) into tResArray
put tResArray["data"]["translations"][1]["translatedText"] into fld "myField"
```

There is lots more to this API, which documented in the first link above, but this is the basic process for using web service APIs in LiveCode. If you'd like more info on using web services in LiveCode I've written an introductory lesson on this topic here:

http://livecode.byu.edu/internet/webServicesintro.php